# C# Linq flatdto build Menu

Tags: c#, linq, menu

I have a flatdto that I am using to build a pick list menu. The menu should be build using the ID as the parent item in the menu and then all the sub menu should fall under that menu. I can only get the parent items to display if  I remove the null reference not sure what I am missing to get the child menu items to display.

```
List<DiseaseFlatDto> diseases;
                diseases = resp.Data.Where(d => d.Reference != null).ToList();

                //diseases = resp.Data.ToList();
     return SetPicklistItems(diseases.OrderBy(d => d.Name), null);


    private IEnumerable<PicklistItemModel> SetPicklistItems(IEnumerable<flatDto> diseases, int? Id)
    {
        return diseases.Where(d => d.Id == Id).Select(d => new PicklistItemModel
        {
            Value = d.Id.ToString(),
            Text = d.Name,
            Reference = d.Reference,
            Items = SetPicklistItems(diseases, d.Id)
        });
    }


Menu UI
A
...AA
...AB
...AC
B
C
...CA


Sample Data
Id      Name
1410    Ford
1411    Honda
1411    Honda Civic
1411    Honda Accord
1417    Jeep
```

Comment: It looks like you are recursively calling SetPicklistItems. Is that what you are trying to do?  Can you post a sample table that shows a few rows of data.

Comment: Yes I am using a recursive to call SetPicklistItems

Comment: The table you posted doesn't have anything recursive.  Usually a recursive table would have a parent ID and a child ID.  I would expect for Hona to see a main number 1400 and child numbers 1401, 1402,...

Comment: The first Where call will fail (presuming your dto Id field is an int not int?) due to passing null on first call.  I would do `Where(d => Id == null || d.Id == Id`.